# How to react to change in Angular <2.x observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, onchange

I have a data service component that is intended to share a BehaviorSubject class variable between a few components.

I have the service set up as such:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SharedStateService {
  private selectedYearMo = new BehaviorSubject('2018-11');
  yearmo = this.selectedYearMo.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeYearmo(yearmo: string) {
    this.selectedYearMo.next(yearmo);
    this.yearmo = this.selectedYearMo.asObservable();
    console.log("yearmo change request recieved at service");
    console.log("yearmo changed: ", this.yearmo);
  }

  getYearmo(){
    return this.yearmo;
  }
}
```

Each of the components implements the subscription to the observable as follows:

```
...
constructor(private sharedStateService: SharedStateService) {
};
...
getYearMo(): void {
    this.sharedStateService.getYearmo().subscribe(
      (yearmo: any) => {
        console.log("BehaviourSubject test received "+yearmo+" at component.");
        this.cd.markForCheck();
      }
    );
  }
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.getYearMo();
  this.getData();
};
...
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log("detected changes...");
    for (let propName in changes) {
        let change = changes[propName];
        let curVal  = JSON.stringify(change.currentValue);
        let prevVal = JSON.stringify(change.previousValue);
      console.log(curVal);
      console.log(prevVal);
    }
  };
...
```

Right now, when the observable changes, the log message defined in getYearmo appears as expected `BehaviourSubject test received "+yearmo+" at component` but thte `ngOnChanges()` method is never called.  However, I would like a way to handle this sort of things in a proper lifecycle hook like `ngOnChanges()` since eventually I might want to have more than one subscription.

Is there another way to react to changes in my observable that I'm missing?  It seems like this would be a common thing to do but I'm having trouble understanding from the resources I've come across thus far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused with the reactive property of `Observables` and the `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook of Angular.

`ngOnChanges`- [as per the documents](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), is a lifecycle hook aka a callback function that will be called if you have any data bound input properties - that is - properties that is decorated using `@Input` in your Angular. It is **NEVER** used to detect any changes of your `Observables`.

> Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties. The method receives a SimpleChanges object of current and previous property values.
>
> Called before ngOnInit() and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change.

Assuming you are [following the Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges) (which can be seen that your code is almost as exactly as the doc's exammple), you can see that their code has properties that is decorated using `@Input`.

```
@Input() hero: Hero;
@Input() power: string;
```

And that this two properties are actually being "passed into" the component through data-binding, using the square brackets:

```
<on-changes [hero]="hero" [power]="power"></on-changes>
```

So no, `ngOnChanges` is **NOT** the place you want to write your code to react to your Observable changes. It is there for you to write your code to react to the `@Input` changes. `Observable`'s `subscribe` is already there for you to implement whatever you want in the event the `Observables` emit an emission. And to subscribe to your `Observabels`, yes, the best place to do it as `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook.

Comment: That is good insight.  It was confusing at first to understand the role of the observable relative to other data sharing options.